# DynamoDb converting Attribute Values to Types

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a more efficient way of converting dynamo db data into concrete types? For example, when I query the data everything is in:

```
List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>>
```

Is it possible to easily convert the type without having to loop through each item and doing this all manually?

For example I am doing:

```
    return items.Select(item => new Connection
        {
            ConnectionId = Guid.Parse(item["connectionId"].S),
            ClientId = item["clientId"].S,
            ProviderId = item["providerId"].S,
            Scopes = item["scopes"].SS.ToArray(),
            CredentialsId = item["credentialsId"].S,
            Evidences = ToEvidences(item["consentEvidences"].L)
        })
        .ToList();
```

This then returns a list of my type `Connection` however I am explicitly mapping each field. Is there an easier way or a helper library that can do the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found is to use the `Document.FromAttributeMap` function to convert it to a `Document` object and then convert it again to the .NET type using the `DynamoDBContext.FromDocument` method as shown below.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAll(string cityName)
{
    var queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
    {
        TableName = nameof(WeatherForecast),
        KeyConditionExpression = "CityName = :cityName",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
        {
            {":cityName", new AttributeValue(cityName)},
        }
    };
    var response = await _dynamoDbClient.QueryAsync(queryRequest);

    return response.Items.Select(a =>
    {
        var doc = Document.FromAttributeMap(a);
        return _dynamoDbContext.FromDocument<WeatherForecast>(doc);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have luck with the higher-level .NET Document model. It presents more natural data types.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html

Comment: this requires "polluting" the domain classes. I'm using the low-level apis (using `IAmazonDynamoDb` interface directly, and isn't a easier way to convert without using attributes on the classes?